# Misleading errors of SalesForce API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG

Tags: api, oauth, salesforce

I have seen this error when API has been enabled for all the Orgs in question. All I need is a read-only data dump, for which I figured the ("Read your data via the web") Permissions is the one that needs to be granted during OAuth. When this permission was omitted in the App spec, SalesForce API threw a "API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG" error. After changing the spec and asking for the Web part to be granted, this error goes away for some orgs.

Other orgs still throw the same error. Which leads me to believe this error is misleading, either the first situation was a different error or the Org has actually disabled API access, (which I don't need, just need read-only data access). Yet, when asked, during OAuth, the User actually agreed to supplying the data. I have this as scope: "id api web refresh_token", for an authenticated OAuth user.

What gives? What am I missing here? Can't seem to get a consistent process flow, data and in this case a proper error message from SalesForce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually see this for editions that do not have API, e.g. Group Edition and Professional Edition.

Comment: That exceedingly looks to be the case, haven't been able to nail it down yet. Is there a toggle switch for the Account holders to turn for these to start working in GE and PE?

Comment: Not really. They can ask their account rep to temporarily grant them API access. This is usually allowed for up to 30 days in order to load data into the org.

Answer (score -1):

Yep Salesforce support will do this for you - just if you want to use a MAC app such as OneSync to manage contacts on an on-going basis you are stuffed, unless you pay for the Enterprise version - hmm $60/year to $1200 don't think so